# How to check if a div is resizable()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

What seems like a simple thing to do is not playing ball.  **How do I check if an element is resizable?**

Ive tried some testing on jsfiddle without much luck.  Ive tried looking at the official instructions page here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#method-option and a bit of googling and checking for the answer on stackoverflow but still cant get it to give me the correct response.  The below code comes back 'disabled' regardless.

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbKtP/11/

```
$("#a").resizable();

if ($("#a").resizable("option","enable") == true){
   alert("enabled");       
} else {
   alert("disabled");   
}
```

Can anyone solve this resonably simple but perplexing issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "disabled" not "enable". Don't forget to also reverse the boolean when you correct it.

i.e.:

```
if ($("#a").resizable("option","disabled")){
   alert("disabled");   
} else {
   alert("enabled");       
}
```

PS. It's kind of silly to compare to `true` and `false`.

Comment: thanks I can see this works a treat ^^  I find it strange than you can check if its disabled but not enabled.  I know essentially its the same thing.   I only compared it to true/false because of my habbit of cut & paste from google O.o

Comment: `disabled` and `enabled` are just meaningless things to the computer, they are not real booleans with their english meaning. The code simply adds that word to the element, and it doesn't add both words. It could just as easily add the word `rsz`.

Answer (score 21):

You may check for a class added by resizable, if you wisth to know if `resizable()` was called on the element before.

```
$('#a').is('.ui-resizable')
```

The enabled state you can check by reading the `disabled` option (see Ariel's answer).